# Download file from Google Sheets to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to bulk download some files from internet, all URL are listed in column A (as the example shows). Is there any method to bulk download all files to Google Drive without doing it manually?

[image: example]

Comment: please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to do it.

You will have to create a function in Apps Script to get each Url from the sheet and then save the result as a new file on your Drive.

To do so you have to use the sheets functions [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) or [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
to get the cells with the URL, once you have them you will have to iterate over each cell and [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

And then for each URL you have to use a function like this, which gets the data from the url and creates a new file on your Drive:

```
function downloadFile(fileURL) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  var newFile = response.getBlob()
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Your Folder');
  var result = folder.createFile(newFile);
}
```